# Copy modified records from one Database to another in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two mysql databases in different physical locations. All CRUD operations in one table are required to be replicated in my second database's given table. Column names are different, but data types are same. For the sake of performance, better to happen this as scheduled.

In most of questions are about dumping/writing entire table to another. But I need to copy only the changes(due to CRUD operations as scheduled ). Anyone let me know any solution please.

Answer (score 1):

ON INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE trigger + cronjob will solve your problem. That should not be too difficult to implement.

Although, I would personally consider using native MySQL replication. It will require renaming the table and updating all affected code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you let me know any resource so that I can go through and have an idea practically ?